# How to upload Image completely using TIdFtp

Tags: delphi, file-upload, ftp, indy

I'm trying to upload an image via TIdFtp from Delphi, but some part of the uploaded image is white.
The uploaded image is like below:

[image]

`TransferType` is set to `ftBinary`. I think it's not related to image size because I tried with different images with different sizes. Also, I tried with and without compressing JPG too.

The source code is written in this way:

```
var
JPG: TJPEGImage;
begin
JPG := TJPEGImage.Create;
JPG.Assign(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
JPG.SaveToStream(MS);
IdFTP1.Connect;
IdFTP1.Put(MS, strFileName);
IdFTP1.Disconnect;
end
```

Additional information

The log file of upload process is like below:

```
Stat Connected.
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32: 220 ProFTPD Server (ProFTPD) [**********]<EOL>
Sent 21/09/2023 20:00:32: HOST ***********<EOL>
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32: 504 ftp.*********: Unknown hostname provided<EOL>
Sent 21/09/2023 20:00:32: USER ********<EOL>
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32: 331 Password required for ******<EOL>
Sent 21/09/2023 20:00:32: PASS *********<EOL>
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32: 230 User *********** logged in<EOL>
Sent 21/09/2023 20:00:32: FEAT<EOL>
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32: 211-Features:<EOL>
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32:  AUTH TLS<EOL> CCC<EOL> CLNT<EOL> CSID<EOL> EPRT<EOL>
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32:  EPSV<EOL> HOST<EOL> LANG en-US.UTF-8*<EOL> MDTM<EOL> MFF modify;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;<EOL> MFMT<EOL> MLST modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.groupname*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;UNIX.ownername*;<EOL> PBSZ<EOL> PROT<EOL> RANG STREAM<EOL> REST STREAM<EOL> SIZE<EOL> SSCN<EOL> TVFS<EOL> UTF8<EOL>211 End<EOL>
Sent 21/09/2023 20:00:32: CLNT Indy 10.6.2.5341<EOL>
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32: 200 OK<EOL>
Sent 21/09/2023 20:00:32: TYPE I<EOL>
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32: 200 Type set to I<EOL>
Sent 21/09/2023 20:00:32: SYST<EOL>
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32: 215 UNIX Type: L8<EOL>
Sent 21/09/2023 20:00:32: TYPE I<EOL>
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32: 200 Type set to I<EOL>
Sent 21/09/2023 20:00:32: PASV<EOL>
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32: 227 Entering Passive Mode *******,246,62).<EOL>
Sent 21/09/2023 20:00:32: STOR ZZP7nY.jpg<EOL>
Recv 21/09/2023 20:00:32: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for ZZP7nY.jpg<EOL>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673891/indy-upload-memorystream-to-ftp for an example

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I tried it but the problem continues.

Comment: @mjn All properties of Indyftp  is like the example you mentioned and the codes are the same, but the problem is exists.

Comment: Can you upload the same image file correctly using GUI/commandline FTP client running on the same machine, where your application fails to do so?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it is not necessary to set `MS.Position=0` as `TIdFTP.Put()` will automatically upload a `TStream` from `Position=0` by default. There are optional parameters to change that behavior when needed (ie, for resuming broken uploads, etc)

Comment: @HolyThirteen the code shown is correct (minus the lack of `try..finally` to avoid memory leaks if `TIdFTP.Put()` fails), so the problem has to be somewhere else. If you save the `TMemoryStream` to file before uploading, is the image correct? How are you displaying the images that you upload?

Comment: Log file of upload operation attached to the post as additional information.

Comment: @HolyThirteen that log provides no useful info to diagnose your issue, and doesn't answer my questions

Comment: @RemyLebeau I saved the uploading image to a file right before put command. The saved file is without any problem but the problem with uploaded file is exists.

Comment: @HolyThirteen Again, I ask, how exactly are you looking at the *uploaded* file? Are you displaying it on a web page? Are you downloading it back to your machine and opening it locally? Have you checked whether the bytes/hash of the uploaded file is identical to the local file? `TIdFTP.Put()` simply transmits the raw bytes as-is, so unless the file is getting truncated on the server end, I don't see how this code can cause the issue you are seeing. And unfortunately, it does not appear your FTP server supports commands to hash files, so you would have to verify the uploaded file in other ways

Comment: @RemyLebeau I displayed the uploaded file in several ways. I opened it on server, downloaded it on local computer and opened it, and displayed it on a web page but in all of them the result is the same as I post. I haven't checked whether the bytes/hash of the uploaded file is identical to the local file, but if I know how should I do, I will do that.